# how in the numberOfItemsInSection method to return the number equal to the value that I set in the slider from another view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift3

I am still learning swift, and I am trying to create a UICollectionView that would return the number of items that I set in the initial view controller using the slider, but my code doesn't work, how would I do this? Here is my code below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    //MARK: - Outlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            firstLabel.text = "0"
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var firstSlider: UISlider! {
        didSet {
            
            firstSlider.value = 0
            firstSlider.minimumValue = 0
            firstSlider.maximumValue = 500
        }
    }
    
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    @IBAction func firstSliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
        
        let firstSliderAction = Int(round(sender.value))
        firstLabel.text = "\(firstSliderAction)"
    }
 }



// CollectionViewController


private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    var vc: ViewController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController

        

    }

    

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return Int(vc.firstSlider.value)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    
        
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? You're looking at the slider and returning its value as an Int. That seems like the right sort of thing. (Do not use the meaningless fluff-phrase "does not work" in your reply, please.)

Comment: You should research how to pass data between view controllers. In your code, you're creating a new instance of your view controller with the slider, as opposed to using the view controller instance that was created from your Storyboard definition. Since you create a new instance, you're always getting the initial default value of the slider.

Comment: How do you move from `ViewController` to `CollectionViewController`?  Via a segue?  If so, you should implement `prepare(for:)` in your `ViewController` - This will let you get a reference to your destination `CollectionViewController`.  You can then set a property on the destination view controller with the current value of your slider.

Answer (score 0):

First let me tell you why your code is not working as expected.

```
vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
```

Every time when we initiate view controller from corresponding storyboard it will create new object of that view controller, so based on that **vc object will not have those value** which has been set by earlier user interaction, in-short for that object `didSet` haven't called yet.

Now how you can achieve the above,
Well first we need to observe how you are navigating from `ViewController` to `CollectionViewController` based on code it looks like you are using segue so you can do below stuff.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstSlider: UISlider!
    var sliderValue:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            firstLabel.text = "\(sliderValue)"
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpInitialValues()
    }

    func setUpInitialValues() {
        firstSlider.value = 0
        firstSlider.minimumValue = 0
        firstSlider.maximumValue = 500
    }
    // Value changed action
    @IBAction func firstSliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
        self.sliderValue = Int(round(sender.value))
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "navigateCollection" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? CollectionViewController {
                destinationVC.sliderValue = self.sliderValue
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
    private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var sliderValue:Int = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return sliderValue
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return cell
}
}
```